# Set alignment of XRPictureBox at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to create a XtraReport Template class, which get a report object and transform it to our Company design. At first, I create a ReportHeaderBand which get an XRPictureBox for the Logo. How can I place the XRPictureBox at the Right side of my ReportHeaderBand?

This is what I am doing so far:

```
internal class Kopfbereich: ReportHeaderBand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erstellt ein Objekt für den Kopfbereich eines Reports
        /// </summary>
        public Kopfbereich()
        {
            DruckeLogo();
        }

        private void DruckeLogo()
        {
            XRPictureBox picBox = new XRPictureBox();
            picBox.Visible = true;
            picBox.Sizing = ImageSizeMode.AutoSize;
            picBox.Image = Resources.Brillux_Logo_Reports_ohne_Text;
            this.Controls.Add(picBox);
        }
    }

    //This Method is from other class and should print my report with template
    public XtraReport DruckeMitVorlage(XtraReport report)
    {
        Kopfbereich kopfbereich = new Kopfbereich();
        report.Bands.Add(kopfbereich);
        return report;
    }
```

I want to create it at Runtime to get an dynamic Template. So Designer is not an option.

I tried following code line to set the XRPictureBox on the right.

```
picBox.LocationF = new PointF(Report.PageWidth - picBox.WidthF - Report.Margins.Right.Width, 0);
```

But the Logo becomes displayed half on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add this `XRPictureBox` control to the `report header band` rather than `this.Controls`. It may control the picture edit to print on the top of the report rather than printing on another pages..

check the code snippet:

```
// Check if the TopMargin band is already present in the report. 
if(Bands.GetBandByType(typeof(ReportHeaderBand)) == null) {
    // Create a new TopMargin band and add it to the report. 
    ReportHeaderBandtmBand = new ReportHeaderBand();
    Bands.Add(tmBand);

    // Create a picture object
    XRPictureBox picBox = new XRPictureBox();
    picBox.Visible = true;
    picBox.Sizing = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.ImageSizeMode.AutoSize;
    picBox.Image = Resources.Logo;
    this.Controls.Add(picBox);

    // Add the label to the ReportHeaderBand band. 
    tmBand.Controls.Add(picBox);
}
```

You can place control using report object as below:

```
 // Place the chart onto a report footer
  rep.Bands[BandKind.ReportHeader].Controls.Add(picBox);
```

Reference:
[How to create a report dynamically in the WinForms application](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4657)

Comment: I edited my Post. Sorry dont post complete code. In fact iam doing the same like you i think. I just dont know how to get the XRPictureBox on the right Border (alignment = right). Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: try to add panel to report header and then add this picture control to it.. then try to use before print event to get the point where to place. `Dock` property of the XRControls may be absolute.

Comment: The problem is that i cant get the Point to place. The BeforePrint event just give me a PrintAction and a Cancel. How can i get the Location on the right side of ReportHeaderBand to set this for my XRPictureEdit? There is no alignment Propertie :-(